# How comparison operator for strings works in C++, if strings are numbers?

Tags: c++, string, comparison

Please tell me how less than, greater than operator works for strings if strings are numbers and also have same number of digits. How exactly these operator work ?

For e.g., for the below comparisons-

```
cout<<("3" > "5")<<endl;
cout<<("31" > "25")<<endl;
cout<<("35" > "35")<<endl;
cout<<("38" > "85")<<endl;
cout<<("53" > "55")<<endl;
cout<<("36" > "35")<<endl;
cout<<("53" > "54")<<endl;
```

Output I got from CodeBlocks is-

```
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

Comment: You are comparing **pointers**.  "Does the address of this string happen to be greater than the address of this string?"

Comment: Comparing string literals compares pointers and will not account for the string's content.

Comment: Strings are not numbers. They are 0-terminated arrays of characters. A particular string might contain characters that can be interpreted as a number, but that's a separate step; such a string is not a number.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The behaviour of your code is undefined.

The `const char[]` literals you have entered decay to `const char*` pointers for the purpose of comparison.

And the behaviour of the comparison operators on pointers  is only defined if the pointers are part of the same array; which yours are not.

If you suffix the literals with an s, e.g.
`"3"s` then C++14 onwards will treat that as a std::string and will perform a lexographic comparison.

Answer (score 8):

`"3"` is not a "string", it's a `const` array of `char`s. `const char` arrays can automatically decay to `const char*`. Pointers can be compared with `operator<`.

Comparison of pointers is just comparison between addresses. In this particular case, your comparisons lead to **undefined behavior** as the pointers are unrelated between each other (they're not pointing to objects that belong to the same array).

---

If you really want to lexicographically compare C-style strings, use `std::strcmp`. Otherwise, you should use `std::string` and rely on `std::string::operator<`.